# how to add option(recompile) within this stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, optimization, stored-procedures, parameter-sniffing

In my current environment, I have many instances of stored procedures, just like the one shown below, where a bunch of parameters are passed to the procedure, and then within the procedure a `select exists` is run and based on the result, different logic paths are run within the stored procedure.

I have a couple of questions regarding the procedure below:

1) is it a good candidate for parameter sniffing?

2) how could I add `option(recompile)` within the code?

[There are differences between adding option(recompile) within the code and creating a stored procedure with recompile.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/recompile-hints-and-execution-plan-caching/)

I would be more keen on the `option(recompile)` if that is possible.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_upd_activity]
                    @activityId             INT,
                    @title                  VARCHAR(100), 
                    @description            VARCHAR(MAX),
                    @inclusions             VARCHAR(MAX),
                    @locationId             INT,
                    @imageUriMain           VARCHAR(255),
                    @uploadToBucket         VARCHAR(200),
                    @path                   VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRAN 
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @documentId INT

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM document 
                        WHERE activityId    = @activityId)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO  document 
                        (   [uploadToBucket], [path], [activityId])
            VALUES      (@uploadToBucket, @path, @activityId)

            SET @documentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();


        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE  document
            SET     uploadToBucket  = @uploadToBucket,
                    [path]          = @path,
                    activityId      = @activityId
            WHERE   activityId      = @activityId    

            SET @documentId = 
                (SELECT documentId 
                   FROM document 
                   WHERE activityId = @activityId)
        END

        UPDATE          activity
        SET             title           =       @title,
                        description     =       @description,
                        inclusions      =       @inclusions,
                        locationId      =       @locationId,
                        imageUriMain    =       IsNull(@imageUriMain, imageUriMain),
                        documentId      =       @documentId
        WHERE           activityId      =       @activityId                 

        COMMIT


    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE     @ErrorMessage   nvarchar(max), 
                    @ErrorSeverity  int, 
                    @ErrorState     int;
        SELECT      @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Line ' + 
                                    cast(ERROR_LINE() as nvarchar(5)), 
                                    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
                                    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK;

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
    END CATCH       


END
```

Comment: For recompile this should work `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_upd_activity]
                    @activityId             INT,
                    @title                  VARCHAR(100), 
                    @description            VARCHAR(MAX),
                    @inclusions             VARCHAR(MAX),
                    @locationId             INT,
                    @imageUriMain           VARCHAR(255),
                    @uploadToBucket         VARCHAR(200),
                    @path                   VARCHAR(200)
WITH RECOMPILE AS`.

Comment: @Shanky thank you but I would [prefer option(recompile)](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/recompile-hints-and-execution-plan-caching/) if possible.

Comment: @Shanky There are very few scenarios where you should set that at the procedure level; perhaps zero in modern versions of SQL Server. See [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just gave him option as he was looking for one.

Comment: @marcellomiorelli, Some thoughts, your `ELSE` part can benefit from `OUTPUT` clause I believe. Use a table variable to store the document id in it. So a lookup to the document table can be reduced.

Comment: @Bijujose if you show an example, or tell me how to implement, I can do some tests and see how it behaves

Comment: @marcellomiorelli, here is a  version i created in rextester ,[link](http://rextester.com/QQG4486)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this does not look to be a good candidate for recompile. From the code, it looks like `activityId` is unique and will result in a trivial plan so you'll get the same plan regardless of the parameters passed. Add DDL to your question if this is not the case in your situation.

In cases where the optimal plan differs based on the actual parameter values passed (because these are used in WHERE/JOIN clauses and the optimal plan varies accordingly), you could specify the [`OPTION(RECOMPILE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) query hint on specific problem queries to avoid reusing non-trivial plans. However, if the query is executed quite frequently, the compilation cost could outweigh the benefits. It would be better in that case to use an `OPTIMIZE FOR` hint or use the [query store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-query-store-force-plan-transact-sql) (or plan guides) to coerce a specific plan.